# How to use NetBeans to develop desktop app for Google Drive API

Tags: java, netbeans, google-drive-api

Few years ago, when I'm building a desktop app with Google Drive API by using NetBeans, I need to download all the required jar files manually

https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/tree/master/libs/drive

Now, Google introduces gradle build system, to grab all required libraries seamless.

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'DriveQuickstart'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev170-1.20.0'

}
```

I want to continue to use NetBeans as my development tool, to use Google Drive API, in my legacy desktop app project. (The legacy desktop app is built by using NetBeans previously. I have no intention to switch to other development tools)

I need all libraries in jar files, so that I can include them in NetBeans.

[image]

I thought after running `gradle -q run`, I can find dependencies jar files, in the local folder.

However, I don't find any relevant Google Drive API jar files in local folder.

May I know, how can I download necessary jar files for Google Drive API? Or, in another word, how can I use NetBeans to develop desktop app for Google Drive API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux, I realize, after running `gradle -q run`, all the jar files can be discovered in

```
find ~/.gradle/ -name "*jar"
```

I just simply copy all the jar files to my local project lib folder, and reference to them using NetBeans.